# "Hello World" with Java annotations

Tags: java, annotations

Problem description: Compile 2 jar files independently, without having to include each other on classpath; and at runtime, include both and invoke main() in one jar to print a string on stdout. Parts of the output string have to come from the 2nd jar.

Constraints: The solution cannot be IDE-dependent or use any other jar files.

Answering what have I done so far: My Solution is described below.

Reason to ask the question: I am trying to figure out if/how to use annotations to solve this problem (hopefully in a more elegant manner), but cannot find any suitable documentation or tutorial. I appreciate any pointer(s) for that also.

My Solution: A batch file (on Unix, please change the backslash to forward slash, semicolon to colon and the rem's to #) as follows:

```
rem Compile and package the testing class (Main) without any library
javac -d target core\*.java
cd target
jar cvf ..\main.jar .\core
cd ..

rem Compile and package the Greeting and Greeted classes as a library
javac -d lib impl\*.java
cd lib
jar cvf ..\mylib.jar .\impl
cd ..

rem Use the two parts above at runtime and execute main() in Main class
java -cp main.jar;mylib.jar core.Main
```

There are 2 files in the impl directory and 2 in the core, as follows:

/* File: impl/Greeting.java */

```
package impl;

public class Greeting {
    public String getGreeting () {
        return "Hello";
}}
```

/* File: impl/Greeted.java */

```
package impl;

public class Greeted {
    public String getGreeted () {
        return "world";
}
```

/* File: core/Main.java */

```
package core;

public class Main {

    private String  greeting = "Learn annotations",     greeted = "keep using Java",

            // Can read the following 4 values from a configuration file, too
            // Trying to see if we can get these using Java annotations

            greetingClassName = "impl.Greeting",    greetingMethod = "getGreeting",
            greetedClassName = "impl.Greeted",  greetedMethod = "getGreeted";

    public Main () {
        try {
            MyRunTime runTime = new MyRunTime();

            Object gting = runTime.getInstance(greetingClassName),
                gted  = runTime.getInstance(greetedClassName),

                g1Str = runTime.getResponseNoArg (gting, greetingMethod),
                g2Str = runTime.getResponseNoArg (gted, greetedMethod);

            if (g1Str instanceof String)    greeting = (String) g1Str;
            if (g2Str instanceof String)    greeted = (String) g2Str;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println ("Error in Library loading: " + ex.getMessage());
    }}

    public void greet () {
        System.out.println (greeting + ", " + greeted + "!");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Main().greet();
}}
```

/* File: core/MyRunTime.java */

```
package core;

import  java.lang.reflect.*;

public  class  MyRunTime {

    public Object getResponseNoArg (Object anInstance, String methodName) throws
                    NoSuchMethodException,
                        IllegalAccessException,
                        InvocationTargetException {
        Method method = anInstance.getClass().getMethod (methodName);
        return method.invoke (anInstance);
    }

    public Object getInstance (String className) throws 
                    ClassNotFoundException,
                    InstantiationException,
                    IllegalAccessException {
            Class c = Class.forName (className);
            return c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

That's it. I would also like not to mess with the ClassLoader unless absolutely necessary. Once I get a handle on how to do this with annotations, I can look into passing arguments and go forward. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You say, "I am trying to figure out if/how to use annotations to solve this problem." Why? What is there about annotations that makes you want to use them for the described problem? Is this homework? Are there *additional* directions that you haven't given us?

Comment: Why? Inquiring minds want to know. What is there...? Somehow most frameworks I have worked with use annotations for dependency injection/IoC/whatever you call it. Creators of these frameworks are no doubt smart people, and I am trying to understand their logic. And no, this is not any homework. Additional directions: I am not sure what you mean, but what I described is pretty much a complete description. From your comment, should I assume that the answer is "Annotations have nothing to do with the problem described"?

Comment: Yes, that would be my opinion. I do not think that Annotations would add much in the way of solving your problem description. Most of the Annotation usage that I've seen involves determining additional *behavior* for a class, not how to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Annotations for this - it's probably worth covering what Annotations are and where they are best used.

Instead I would do something like:

- Place different files in each jar
- A main class to each jar file, which does the same thing: list the files on the classpath

I think that would meet the project requirements.

To list the files on the classpath you could so something like:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable {
    final String list = System.getProperty( "java.class.path" );
    for (String path : list.split( ";" )) {
      java.io.File object = new java.io.File( path );
      if ( object.isDirectory() )
        for ( String entry : object.list() ) { 
          java.io.File thing = new java.io.File( entry );
          if ( thing.isFile() )
            System.out.println( thing );
          else if( object.isFile() )
            System.out.println( object );
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the problem. While compiling "a.jar" containing the Main.main(String []) method, we do not know the existence of "b.jar" or even the classes it contain. The Main class does not know the objects it needs or the methods to be called (variables xxClassName and xxMethod in my example are to be read in from a configuration file at runtime). What you are suggesting is to scan every jar file on classpath and check if the named object (class) is there in one of them. I can already do that with Class.forName(), and use reflection to check for the method. This is what I am doing now.

Comment: What I am looking for is how I can read in an annotation (e.g., greetingClassName) with a value (e.g., Greeting), and then at runtime find a class annotated as "@Greeting". This way, I can have several implementations of the Greeting class (in different jar files or even packages), and pick the one with correct annotation. Is this a good way to use annotations, or am I totally off the mark?

Comment: If you define an annotation in jar A, you will create a compile & runtime dependency in all the jar's you use it within - which violates the specification.

Comment: This is what I am trying to untangle. I want to read the name of an interface from a config file (lets say greetable), and at runtime, find the class that implements greetable, create its instance and so on. (1) Where do I define the interface (perhaps in "b.jar", since the implementation is also in "b.jar"). Do you think I can eliminate compile dependendy this way?